# how to use segues from buttons to different tabs

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, segue

hi i am creating an application in which mainly i have used storyboard,

-home screen contains few buttons,
-then i added a tab bar controller 
- then i connected 1 button to main tab bar controller window, when pressed it takes to main tab bar controller.
Question:
how do i add 1 button to 1 particular tab ? is it possible by using segues or i have to use another approach ??

i have tried to use this code

```
FirstViewController *_strong = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentedViewController:_strong animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

but it doesnt work its showing an error : no visible @interface

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be something wrong in the header file of class FirstViewController.It may be lack of declartion segment like:
    @interface
    @property int xxxx;
    @end